# How to dynamically specify database credentials with Azure Reporting Services (SSRS)

Tags: azure, reporting-services

#### Summary

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services on Azure. I want to dynamically specify the connection string *including the credentials* at runtime. I run the reports by embedding a ReportViewer control in an ASPX page.

I can make this work *on premise* with SSRS 2012 as long as I specify an Execution Account on the SSRS. However, on Azure Reporting Services I can't specify an Execution Account so it doesn't work.

My question is - how do I make this work on Azure? Specifically, how do I specify the database connection string *including credentials* at runtime when using Azure Reporting Services rather than on-premise.

#### Details

When you do this on-premise, these are the key steps;

- Set your report to use an embedded connection.
- Define a parameter, say "ConnectionString"
- In your embedded data source, set the Connection string to "[@ConnectionString]" (you can also use the expression builder to construct a connection string from different params but it's the same difference).
- In your embedded data source set Credentials to "Do not use credentials".
- Make sure you have specified an Execution Account on SSRS
- In your ASPX page, do something like     `this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("ConnectionString", connectionString, false));`

On SSRS on Azure, you cannot specify an Execution Account so therefore the above doesn't work.

In essence, if you try to set "Do not use credentials" and you do *not* have an Execution Account specified, you will get this error:

> The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified. Tracing ID is: XXX. Machine name is XXX. (rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting)

#### What I have tried

I have tried quite a few different things so far, including specifying dummy credentials in the embedded data source. The *only* way I can make this work with Azure is if I specify valid database credentials directly in the embedded data source.
I have also seen some advice around trying to use the "SQL Server" type connection string instead of "Azure SQL" but it doesn't seem to make any different locally and, in any case, I can't deploy to Azure unless I set it to Azure SQL. I have also experiemented with `this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials` but that doesn't seem to help either; When stepping through the code I get the error the first time I try to communicate with the report, even if that communication is the call to try to set the credentials.

What I find most frustrating about this is that it seems like an entirely illogical dependency; The database credentials you specify in the embedded data source cannot be used to actually run the report (as they are just SQL credentials) and the Execution Account is a Windows account that cannot access the database. So, it looks like an entirely arbitrary dependency for no practical reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution if you are able to create a general purpose "ReportUser" windows account on your server and give this account viewer access to your reports.

You can get around this by adding two parameters to your report.
1. @DatabaseServerName
2. @DatabaseName

Then in your report data source set the connection expression to:

```
="Data Source="+Parameters!DatabaseServerName.Value+";Initial Catalog="&Parameters!DatabaseName.Value
```

When developing the reports you should add a TEST data source to the report that points to a valid development endpoint then prior to deployment to your production server set all the datasets to point back to the data source using the expression above.

In order for this to work you will need to create a "ReportUser" account on your production server and set the credentials of your dynamic data source to the username and password of this account.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Yes, the problem is that on Azure Reporting Services I haven't got access to set up Windows users. What you are describing is a variation on the way I have outlined in my question that I can make it work on-premise. This is only a problem with Azure Reporting Services.